# Showing image from URL in ionic 2

Tags: html, ionic-framework

I have this function for show image from URL, but when my image is change in server, then I do recall the function for showing my newest image, the image still show last image not current image.

```
doRefresh(refresher) {
this.loading = this.loadingController.create({content : "Please Wait..."});
    this.loading.present();
    this.http.get('MY URL')
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data =>
    {
        for(var i = 0; i<data.respone.length; i++){
          if (i==0) {
                        this.items = [{id: i ,img: data.respone[i].URL, desc: data.respone[i].name}];
                    } else {
                        this.items.push({id: i ,img: data.respone[i].URL, desc: data.respone[i].name});
                    }
        }

        this.loading.dismissAll();
    }, err => {
        alert(err);
        this.loading.dismissAll();
    }); 
 refresher.complete();
 }
```

and this my html

```
 <div *ngFor="let x of items">
  <img src= "{{x.img}}" > 
 </div>
```

What is the simple way to make image change to new updatest image, whenever I call that function. help me !

Comment: simply you cant ..we can not identify from ionic app whether the server content change or not ..try any alternative way to do that

Comment: i dont need my ionic app know whether the image has change or not,, the thing I need is whenever I call that function, the changing of image following the server that i've set it to new image. cuse in my case, I have change the image to new image, I call the fucntion after image in server change, but the image still show image before I change that, do you understand what i mean?